# React high order component blocking propagation of props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap, high-order-component

I wrote a React/Typescript high order component to enable showing/hiding components based on the user's permissions.

It was working great until I tried it with ReactBootstrap NavDropdown. Clicking wrapped MenuItems does not close the menu.

I realized that the "onSelected" prop (applied by the NavDropdown component) was not being propagated down to the MenuItem. To attempt to fix this, I added code to manually propagate the props down but the click still does not close the menu.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Update: Upon further testing, even wrapping in a React.Fragment causes this issue.

Nav:

```js
export class SettingsButton extends React.Component<any, any> {
  public render() {
    return <NavDropdown title="My Dropdown" key='settingsButton' id='settingsButton' noCaret >
      <LinkContainer to="/LogIn" onClick={() => { AuthStore.LogOut(); }}>
        <MenuItem>Log Out</MenuItem>
      </LinkContainer>
      <PermissionDependent isAdmin {...this.props} >
        <LinkContainer to="/OperationsEditor">
          <MenuItem>Operation</MenuItem>
        </LinkContainer>
      </PermissionDependent>
    </NavDropdown >;
  }
}
```

Wrapper:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { ReactElement } from 'react';

interface AdminItemProps {
  isAdmin?: boolean;
  isReadOnly?: boolean;
  canViewInventories?: boolean;
  canViewFinancial?: boolean;
}

export class PermissionDependent extends React.Component<AdminItemProps & any, any> {
  public render() {
    let canView = false;
    if (this.props.isAdmin && this.props.isAdmin === true){ // AuthStore.currentUser.isAdmin) {
      canView = true;
    }
    const { children } = this.props;
    return <React.Fragment>{canView && this.ProcessChildren(children, { ...this.props })}</React.Fragment>;
  }

  ProcessChildren(children: any, props: any) {
    if (children instanceof Array) {
      const result = (children as Array<React.ReactNode>).map(child => {
        if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
          return this.ApplyChildProps(child, { ...this.props });
        }
      });
      return result;
    }
    else {
      const child: React.ReactNode = children;
      var mapped = this.ApplyChildProps(child, { ...this.props });
      return mapped;
    }
  }

  ApplyChildProps(child: React.ReactNode, props: any) {
    if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
      const childProps = child.props as any;
      const newProps: any = {};
      
      const reflectedTypes: any = (child.type as any).propTypes;
      if (reflectedTypes) {
        Object.keys(reflectedTypes).map(key => {
          if (key != "children" && !childProps[key]) {
            const value = props[key];
            if (value) {
              newProps[key] = value;
            }
          }
        });
      }
      const childChildren: any = childProps["children"];
      const clonedChildren: any = this.ProcessChildren(childChildren, props);
      const finalProps: any = { key: Math.random(), children: clonedChildren, ...newProps, ...childProps };
      return React.cloneElement(child, finalProps);
    }
    return child;
  }

}
```

Comment: your wrapper component is way more complex than it needs to be (also not an HoC in the commonly used sense of the term). All you want is to prevent rendering children if some prop is false, right?

Comment: Yes. Originally, I just returned props.children or not. But the MenuItems ended up with no "onSelected", so I thought doing this would fix it. RE: HOC, Sorry if I got my term wrong. I'm pretty new to React... What is the proper term?